# how to find change a set of differential equation to the first-order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

we have x(t) and y(t) are the function of t which satisfy: 
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=f(x,y)$$
$$g(x,y)=0$$
where f(x,y) and g(x,y) do not contain any derivative of x(t) and y(t).

**Qestion: How to find the $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=???$.**

For example, 
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=-xy$$
$$g(x,y)=x(2-y)-1=0$$
we can get $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{y^2(1-2x)}$

Is there a general way to find $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate the constraint with respect to $t$:
$$ g_x \dot x + g_y \dot y = 0. $$
Can plug in that $\dot x = f(x,y)$ to obtain
$$ \dot y = - \frac{g_x}{g_y} f. $$
Checking with your example - $f = - xy$ and $g = x(2-y) - 1$ which implies that $g_x = 2 -y$ and $g_y = -x$. Plugging into our equation we obtain
$$ \dot y = - \frac{2 - y}{-x} (-xy) = y(y-2) = - \frac{y}{x}.$$
Maybe it is possible to convert it to your form, or maybe it is a typo.

Comment: Thanks, it is the same actually.